# How can set a hard maximum recursion depth in Perl?

Tags: perl, recursion

Although in some cases I might want to allow deep recursions in my code, I want to be able to disable it in certain cases (like while testing).

I know that when using the debugger I can use `$DB::deep` to specify the maximum recursion depth, and the feature I'm after is basically the same but usable even when not in the debugger.

I took a look in CPAN, but I couldn't find anything. And a search on PerlMonks lead me to a thread about [changing the behaviour of the deep recursion *warning*](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=324564). What I'm after is a to be able to block recursions altogether (eg. `die` if the recursion gets too deep).

Does this feature exist?

Bonus points if the solution allows me to localise it, so that I can control the scope of a maximum recursion depth.

Comment: If you look at the perl code (at least here https://github.com/Perl/perl5 ), you'll see that the threshold for the warning `PERL_SUB_DEPTH_WARN` is used for both the warning and the actual limit. But, as others have said, you need to recompile your perl binary to change it.

Comment: Have you considered not using recursion? Most problems can be solved without it and then you could easily limit how many items they process.

Comment: @briandfoy The reason I'm looking for this is to catch involuntary recursions, particularly in tests. There are no deep recursions in the codebase this would be for, so this would make sure that if a deep recursion _is_ detected by Perl, then the test would fail without potentially bringing the machine down to a crawl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a previous answer mentions, you can only change the level that triggers the warning, by recompiling Perl.

But you can make the existing warning fatal like this:

```
use warnings FATAL => 'recursion';
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [perldoc perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html):

> **Deep recursion on subroutine "%s" (W recursion)**
>   This subroutine has
>   called itself (directly or indirectly) 100 times more than it has
>   returned. This probably indicates an infinite recursion, unless you're
>   writing strange benchmark programs, in which case it indicates
>   something else.
>
> This threshold can be changed from 100, by recompiling the perl
>   binary, setting the C pre-processor macro PERL_SUB_DEPTH_WARN to the
>   desired value.

So it seems you cannot localize the behavior unless you modify the `perl` binary.

Comment: Hm. Not looking good. In any case, that applies to modifying the threshold for the _warning_. Being able to modify that threshold is not so important to me as being able to make Perl `die` if / when that warning fires.